# Do not show moustache syntax before load

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

Do you have any idea how can I hide moustache syntax before replace it?

I want my script to do it, and not depend on user implementation since it's for a library.

You can see here the moustache showing before it's replaced by the corresponding value.
https://fastframework.ga/blog/

Comment: You can probably have a css class to hide the content which you remove after the rendering of mustache

Comment: That means the dev using the framework needs to add the class to the element. But what if his html is ```<body>{{ date }} <div class="iWantThisToShow">a</div></body>``` I don't want to force him to add a element to style the mustache. That's html is to define content, not to add clases to style stuff. Is there any way to css based on a pattern or regexp?